# replace Drawable with downloaded Bitmap

Tags: android

I'm trying to replace resource drawables with downloaded bitmaps.

To achieve this, I attach the activity to a custom base context like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(new InterceptingContextWrapper(newBase));
    }

    private class InterceptingContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {

        private Resources resources;

        public InterceptingContextWrapper(Context base) {
            super(base);
            resources = new Resources(base.getAssets(), base.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(), base.getResources().getConfiguration()){
                @Override
                public Drawable getDrawable(int id, Theme theme) throws NotFoundException {
                    String resourceName = getResourceName(id);
                    if (id == R.drawable.sample) {
                        Log.i("InterceptionTest", "gotcha");
                    }
                    Log.i("InterceptionTest", "Getting drawable for resource " + resourceName);
                    return super.getDrawable(id, theme);
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public Resources getResources() {
            return resources;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `getDrawable` method is only triggered for images referenced via `app:srcCompat`. Images referenced via `android:src` or `android:background` are not retrieved via `getDrawable`; some images (mainly images referenced from the android namespace (`@android:drawable/...` ) show up, though. (but not all)

If I subclass `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity` this doesn't help either.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you donot use `imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard0/path/To/downloaded/ImageFile.jpg"));` ?

Comment: As of API 25, there is no officially supported way to intercept drawable inflation at the Resources level. You will need to find a different approach.

Comment: There are a seemingly infinite number of [image-loading libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46). If your images are coming from multiple places, perhaps you should abstract out how those images get populated, leveraging an existing library that can handle multiple image source locations.

Comment: @k3b: That approach results in decoding the image on the main application thread, which leads to jank.

Comment: i have an Activity based cache. So leaking should not be a problem. and i want a layout that is using certain bundled images be customizable with download packages. preparing every possible imageview seems too much overhead instead of a generic solution.